# How to set the height of a programatically created ImageView inside of a TableRow inside of a TableLayout?

Tags: java, android

```
TableLayout mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        JSONArray Rows = obj.getJSONArray("Rows");
        for(int i=0;i<Rows.length();i++) {
            TableRow Row1 = new TableRow(this);
            JSONArray RowN = Rows.getJSONArray(i);
            for(int j=0;j<RowN.length();j++) {
                ImageView Tile=new ImageView(this.getApplicationContext());
                Tile.setImageResource(0);
                Tile.setBackgroundColor(0x4133FF70);
                Row1.addView(Tile);
            }
            mTableLayout.addView(Row1);
        }
```

This is my code. In the loop, ImageViews are created without an image to display and just a background.

Using

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.dl_image);
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
```

just returns a NullPointerexception and I don't have more ideas what to try.

Edit:

The solution turned out to be

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(120, 120);
                Tile.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dl_image); -> you have to cast it into an ImageView.....are you doing that?

Comment: I copied this code from another post, but I actually used Tile..getLayoutParams().width = 120;

Comment: What else is there in the row. Can you let me know that. And why adding to cell programatically, you can create a custom cell in UI and the use cell to populate your table using that

Comment: There is nothing else in the row, just these created ImageViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting null pointer exception due to `.getLayoutParams().width`, did you set params yet? Answer is no then how can you expect params to be there.

Update this to from

```
Tile.getLayoutParams().width = 120;
```

to

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120, 120);
Tile.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: If I do this my Views just disappear for some reason.

Comment: Ok the problem was that your code had LinearLayout. I have replaced it with TableRow and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to set the height,width of your imageview. Just remember to keep it less than the cell height ot you will have to increase the cell height manually as well.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dl_image);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: If I add this code my views completely disappear for some reason.